# getting substring with few manipulations

Tags: javascript, string

In my javascript (angularjs) application, I have a string `var sample = "Der_Code_And_Tray_29"`, I need to have a function for which we pass the original string `sample`, then the function should traverse the string from the end to find the first occurence of underscore and deletes the string till then and return the remaining string.  So in essence the resulted string returned by the function should be `"Der_Code_And_Tray"`, ie., `_29` should be removed. I have tried few ways like, finding the length of the string from there decrementing the index to get the underscore then noting down this index and removing the string content between these two indexes. I am feeling there should be smart way of doing it. Can any one suggest me any better way of doing it?

The replacement after last underscore with empty space should take place only if, the string after last underscore contains only numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace the portion from the last underscore to the end with nothing:

```
sample.replace(/_[^_]*$/, '')
```

Comment: torazaburo, the replacement with empty string should only take place, if the string after last underscore contains only numbers. For example if the string is "Der_Code_And_Tray_2f9" then the result should be the original string as it i.e.,  "Der_Code_And_Tray_2f9" but not "Der_Code_And_Tray". In my original question I missed to make this clarification. Sorry for that. But your solution returns "Der_Code_And_Tray" for both  "Der_Code_And_Tray_2f9" and  "Der_Code_And_Tray_29"

Comment: OK, so how would you fix the regular expression to make it work that way?

Answer (score 1):

> So in essence the resulted string returned by the function should be
>   "Der_Code_And_Tray", ie., _29 should be removed

try this simplest one

```
 sample = sample.substring(0,sample.lastIndexOf("_"));
```

or another, bit more generic (replace -1 with -2 to remove last two items)

```
var sample = "Der_Code_And_Tray_29";
sample = sample.split("_").slice(0,-1).join("_");
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split your string into an array of substrings, then remove the index of the array by [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) then [join("_")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the elements of an array into a string:

```js
var sample = "Der_Code_And_Tray_29";
sample=sample.split('_');
sample.pop();
sample = sample.join('_')
console.log(sample)
```